# Media Library Won't Display Any Images

Tags: uploads, media-library

I've got a local install of WP and I've copied my live site's uploads dir to the proper spot in wp-content, but Media Library isn't showing a single image.

I've recursively set uploads and subsequent dirs to 755, that didn't fix it. I checked the upload_path in wp_options and it's blank like it is on the live server.

FYI, the import of posts I did came from a multi-site install where the live site is.

I'm at a loss as to where I can fix this missing link to the uploads folder. Posts are seeing the images in the uploads and rendering fine with the local dev url path in the images.

Thanks for any guidance!

[image: my empty media library on local]

[image: my folder structure for the local install]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Went through and re-added the images (originals, not generated, those I manually deleted) using Add From Server plugin as seen here:

https://www.lockedowndesign.com/ftp-uploads-are-not-visible-wp-media-library/

Answer (score 1):

Because entries in the media screen is a post/page type of thing. That Media page doesn't grab files from your upload directory. You have to go through the 'upload' process to create a proper media entry, which will point to the uploaded file's location in the upload folder.

Although there is probably a plugin that will scan your upload directory, and make media entries for each of them. You used one of them.